# Magento: Getting latest products depending on store view / language?

Tags: magento

I wrote my own `list.phtml` to display latest products on my home page. The code in my `list.phtml` file is like this:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('news_from_date')->addAttributeToSelect('news_to_date');
```

This gety products and also displys them like I want, except for the language. No matter what language I choose, its always in english. Do I have to add a filter to the collection to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: The trouble is, the product collection is ALREADY loaded, so you can't add additional attributes to it.  You should add this logic to an override against `_getProductCollection`

Comment: you can find the `_getProductCollection` function in the block which is generating collection data for your template.